# Energy of a Real Harmonic Current of Bidegree $(1,1)$ on a Compact Kahler Manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-forms, distribution-theory, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

**Harmonic Currents of Finite Energy and Laminations**, *J. E. Fornaess* and *N. Sibony*, *GAFA, Geom, Funct, Anal*, $2005$, $962-1003$.

Page $968$, Section **Energy of harmonic currents**

According to what is stated in the image attached below,

If $\overline{\partial}S \in L^2$, is $\partial\overline{S} \in L^2$ too?

[image]

Comment: We have $\overline{\bar \partial S} = \partial \overline S$ so the norms of the two are equal. If one is in $L^2$ then the other one is as well.